# Graph Visualization Framework for JavaFX

Tags: javascript, java, data-visualization, graphs

Hey there I'm searching for a Graph Visualization Framework with following specs:

1. JavaFX
2. Integratable into an Eclipse RCP Client
3. Automatical Layout
4. Drag, Drop and Zoomable (or at least possible to implement)
5. Tree Structure possible

I took a look at **yFiles for JavaFX**, but I'm not really sure about it's liscence.
**D3 JavaScript** would be nice, but I'm not sure about the interaction with other parts of the application (e.g. click on a node "view in editor"). And [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679025/graph-visualisation-like-yfiles-in-javafx) seems to handle many things I'm looking for. But the Layout is random and if there is a better option than layouting it by hand or with **Graphviz**, I would prefer not to do it like this.